# signalR is undefined - unable to resolve signalR in aspnet core web app

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I fail to understand why i can't seem to resolve SignalR client library in my aspnet core app. I have included the library, referenced in index.html however when javascript library do not see the reference.

Created a default react project using VS2019 and .net core 3.0 https://github.com/rohitisinhk/signalRIssue

- Added @aspnet/signalr as client side library and confirm it is listed in libman.json
  https://github.com/rohitisinhk/signalRIssue/blob/master/SignalRWebApp/libman.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "provider": "unpkg",
      "library": "@aspnet/signalr@1.1.4",
      "destination": "lib/@aspnet/signalr/",
      "files": [
        "dist/browser/signalr.js",
        "dist/browser/signalr.js.map",
        "dist/browser/signalr.min.js",
        "dist/browser/signalr.min.js.map"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In the html file i referenced the signalr.js
https://github.com/rohitisinhk/signalRIssue/blob/master/SignalRWebApp/ClientApp/public/index.html

```
<script src="/lib/@aspnet/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
```

However in the javascript file i can't seem to resolve signalR

https://github.com/rohitisinhk/signalRIssue/blob/master/SignalRWebApp/ClientApp/src/index.js

```
const signalRConst = signalR;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note you're managing the signalR library with libman, which restores files to `lib/@aspnet/signalr/`, as a result, the npm has no knowledge about the signalR library.

   If you prefer libman over npm, you could change the `signalR` to **`window.signalR`**

   ```
   const signalRConst = window.signalR;
   ```

   Because you're restoring files to `lib/@aspnet/signalr/` instead of `wwwroot/lib/@aspnet/signalr/`, also don't forget to serve static files from the folder `lib/**/*`
2. Or you could use npm to manage the dependencies :

   ```
   > cd ClientApp
   > npm install @aspnet/signalr --save
   ```

   Now you can get the `signalR` by

   ```js
   import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
   ```